# Unity 2D - Instantiated prefab inconsistent position across devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have made a 2d android racing game using unity 5. i was testing the game on my phone(Asus Zenfone 5 with lollipop) it worked perfectly also tested the game on other phone(Samsung Galaxy Duos with jellybean) worked Perfectly as well.

**BUT** when i tested it on Samsung Galaxy s5 the instantiated prefabs have a different Y coordinate value(they start being instantiated from the middle of the screen & they were suppose to instantiate from the top corner).

```
Vector3 carPos = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-0.95f, 1.0f), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
carNo = Random.Range(0, 4);
Instantiate (cars[carNo], carPos, transform.rotation);
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 2D game, you use Vector2s to save coordinates instead of a Vector3s. I believe that this problem occurs, because **the screen size of the different devices** **are different**. To solve this problem try using versatile measurements like Screen.width or Screen.height when positioning. For example, if you were trying to instantiate a car in the top right corner of the screen you would use

---

```
Vector2 carPos = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height);
Instantiate (cars[carNo], carPos, transform.rotation);
```

You can implement the random x coordinates of the cars with Random.Range() with respect to the Screen.width.

Comment: i have been experimenting with your answer but how can i change the screen.height value to the world value in float number.